# Amcharts scrollbar related to one axis only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, amcharts, amcharts4

Is it possible with amcharts 4 to put a scrollbar only on a single value axis of the chart.
I have a chart with one X axis as Date axis, and several Y axes as Value axes. My plan was to make only one of the Y axes with a scrollbar in the chart zoombar.
My problem is that the scrollbar always only changes the entire chart, not just my particular axis.

I tried to set the minZoomCount of the AChsen which should be fixed to a quite large number. This had the desired effect, but unfortunately only while scrolling, so after releasing the mouse the axis jumped back to its default values.

I am using amcharts4 in a react frontend written with typescript.